# vba Conditional Formatting - Run Time Error 13 when clearing Data

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting

My code works for the most part, but when I clear the range of data for a new entry, I get the run-time error 13 and have to end the current macros before I can restart my data entries. On top of that, the cells that were highlighted previous remains highlighted. Any idea how to prevent this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaYBA.jpg)

My code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set lowspec = Range("i6")
Set highspec = Range("m6")
Set i = Intersect(Target, Range("f16:l34"))
If Not i Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target
    Case 1 To lowspec: newcolor = 3
    Case highspec + 1 To 1000: newcolor = 3
End Select
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = newcolor
End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change multiple cells in one operation, `Target` represents the whole range, so  `Select Case Target` is going to be a problem.

Here's how you need to code for this:

- Always assume `Target` could be more than one cell
- Get the intersect between Target and your range of interest, and *operate on that intersect range*: if you just check to see whether there's any intersect and continue to operate on `Target`, that may still include cells outside of your range of interest.
- Perform all your operations on that intersect, cell-by-cell if needed.

Something like:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lowSpec As Double, highSpec As Double, newcolor
    Dim i As Range, c As Range, v

    lowSpec = Me.Range("i6")
    highSpec = Me.Range("m6")

    Set i = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("f16:l34"))
    If Not i Is Nothing Then

        For Each c In i.Cells
           v = c.Value
           If Len(v) > 0 Then
               Select Case v
                   Case 1 To lowSpec: newcolor = 3
                   Case highSpec + 1 To 1000: newcolor = 3
               End Select
           Else
               newcolor = xlNone
           End If
           c.Interior.ColorIndex = newcolor
        Next c

    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the input but i'm not sure if I completely understand the second and third bulletin. Is 'c' the cases?

Comment: C will be each single cell making up the updated range.  See my updated code

Comment: No problem - handling this type of event can be a bit tricky.